# Correct my code: Sort_by 2 attributes, first attribute defers to second attribute if it's one of TWO values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

Given:

```
charges = [
  {payment_method:"card",amount:1000},
  {payment_method:"stripe",amount:500},
  {payment_method:"stripe",amount:1500},
  {payment_method:"card",amount:2000},
  {payment_method:"cash",amount:200},
  {payment_method:"cash",amount:4000},
]
```

I want to sort according to 2 rules:

1. Card OR stripe payment methods should show up first, and then be sorted by amount, lowest to highest
2. Any other payment methods should show up last, and then be sorted by amount, lowest to highest

My current code is moving card or stripe to the front, but not sorting by the amount:

```
charges.sort_by do |obj| 
  [ 
    (["card","stripe"].include? obj["payment_method"]) ? 0 : 1 , 
    obj["amount"]
  ]

# result of MY sort:
charges = [
  {:payment_method=>"card", :amount=>1000},
  {:payment_method=>"stripe", :amount=>500},
  {:payment_method=>"stripe", :amount=>1500},
  {:payment_method=>"card", :amount=>2000},
  {:payment_method=>"cash", :amount=>200},
  {:payment_method=>"cash", :amount=>4000},
]

# result of DESIRED sort:
charges = [
  {:payment_method=>"stripe", :amount=>500},
  {:payment_method=>"card", :amount=>1000},
  {:payment_method=>"stripe", :amount=>1500},
  {:payment_method=>"card", :amount=>2000},
  {:payment_method=>"cash", :amount=>200},
  {:payment_method=>"cash", :amount=>4000},
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code (aside from a missing `end` statement, which I expect didn't survive a cut-and-paste) is that the hashes do not have keys `"payment_method"` and `"amount"` (`charges.first.keys #=> [:payment_method, :amount]`). :-)

With the correction your code works fine:

```
charges.sort_by {|h| [["card", "stripe"].include?(h[:payment_method]) ? 0 : 1, h[:amount]]}
  # [{:payment_method=>"stripe", :amount=> 500},
  #  {:payment_method=>"card",   :amount=>1000},
  #  {:payment_method=>"stripe", :amount=>1500},
  #  {:payment_method=>"card",   :amount=>2000}, 
  #  {:payment_method=>"cash",   :amount=> 200},
  #  {:payment_method=>"cash",   :amount=>4000}]
```

Let's look more closely at what your code was doing.

Because the hashes do not have keys `"paymment_method"` and `"amount"`, `obj["paymment_method"] #=> nil` and `obj["amount"] #=> nil` for all `obj`. Therefore,

```
["card","stripe"].include? obj["payment_method"]
```

becomes

```
["card","stripe"].include? nil
```

which is `false` for all `obj`. Therefore, the first element of the sorting array used by [Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) is always `1`.

`sort_by` uses [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) for ordering arrays.<sup>1</sup> When comparing `obj1["amount"]` and `obj2["amount"]`, the instance method `<=>` defined on the class of `obj1` and `obj2` is employed. In this case

```
 obj1["amount"] <=> obj2["amount"] #=> nil <=> nil
```

We see from

```
nil.method(:<=>).owner #=> Kernel
Array.ancestors        #=> [Array, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

that `NilClass` has an instance method `<=>` that it gets from `Kernel` ([Object#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E)<sup>2</sup>) that returns zero whenever the objects being compared are equal (here `nil <=> nil #=> 0`). The sorting comparison, therefore, is always `[1, nil] <=> [1, nil]`, meaning that the sort is effectively random.

<sup>1 See the latter doc--specifically, the third paragraph--for an explanation of how that is done.</sup>

<sup>2 To understand why `Kernel#<=>` is documented in [Object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Object.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) see the third paragraph at the link.</sup>

Comment: ok so all you've done is moved the parenthesis... but like... why does that work??? why did mine not?

Comment: james, I was in a rush when I posted my answer,  so didn't look at your solution carefully. I just did an edit to explain why your code didn't work.

Comment: oh... the string vs symbol is also a symptom of some code was copied/pasted, some was just hastily written here...